# vboxdrv does not exist. after kernel installation

Tags: 16.04, kernel, virtualbox

I've installed `kernel 4.12.0-041200rc4-generic`, and since then when i open Virtual Box i get this

```
root@machine:~# virtualbox 
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
     Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
     headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.

     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

Tried to fix it and got this:

```
root@machine:~# aptitude install linux-headers-generic virtualbox-dkms 
linux-headers-generic is already installed at the requested version (4.4.0.78.84)
virtualbox-dkms is already installed at the requested version (5.0.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1)
linux-headers-generic is already installed at the requested version (4.4.0.78.84)
virtualbox-dkms is already installed at the requested version (5.0.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1)
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

Guessed i needed to install linux-headers-generic version 4.12

```
root@machine:~# aptitude install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
linux-headers-4.12.0-041200rc4-generic is already installed at the requested version (4.12.0-041200rc4.201706042031)
linux-headers-4.12.0-041200rc4-generic is already installed at the requested version (4.12.0-041200rc4.201706042031)
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `dpkg -l *virtualbox*` and `dkms status` and I'll take a look.

Comment: Try the steps mentioned in this link. It worked for me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291015/how-to-correct-virtualbox-installation